# Make Access file with SQL Server linked table portable via Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-server

I have a SQL Server which contains a table that needs to be updated by different people in different departments.  The easiest solution that we came up was to create a MS Access file, and people can open the file to update the table using Trusted Conenction so each user will not need to input user/pw.

I have created a group with all the users' Windows Authentication account in SQL Server.

Now is when things did not work as planned: I am having trouble creating the MS Access file.  When I create it on my machine, and e-mail it to another user, they get access issues.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: I haven't tried that approach, but I would probably try linking SQL Server into a backend Access db located on the network, then issue users with their own front end linked to the single back-end. I don't have a technical rationale why this might work better, but it seems as if Windows NT will have fewer excuses to say "no" :)

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Also, what is the name of the linked table as it appears in Access? (SQL Server linked tables in Access often have a "dbo_" prefix, e.g. "dbo_Clients", but not always.)

Comment: I'm running Access 2010.  What I am doing so far is just create an Access file where I can access.  Then I send to the users, but they cannot login with the Windows Authentication (while they can if they use a SQL authentication that I provide).  But for control purposes we have to be able to use Windows Authentication.